# Laravel WhereIn not working as expected

Tags: php

I have problem using Laravel wherein. I'm trying to write a query like

```
SELECT * FROM voters WHERE pollingstation_id IN (SELECT pollingstation_id FROM pollingstation_shehia WHERE word_id = 103)
```

I tried two ways and both ways I get the same error, but when I dd I can see the array of returned

Here is the error when I return to view

(2/2) ErrorException
Unexpected data found.
Unexpected data found.
Data missing (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\cufelection\resources\views\voters\votersWordList.blade.php)

Here is when I dd

```
Collection {#2929 ▼
  #items: array:2648 [▶]
}
```

and here is my query

```
$voters = Voter::whereIn('pollingstation_id', function($query) use($id) {
        $query->from('pollingstation_shehia')
              ->where('word_id', $id)
              ->select('pollingstation_id');
})->get();
```

Comment: The error states there is an issue with your view votersWordList.blade.php, it normally says a line number after it. You may want to look there and see what data it is expecting.

Comment: Yes you are right, date field was the problem. Thanks so much!